# opkg in beaglebone white A6 not updating

Tags: beagleboneblack

I am using beaglebone A6. I have istalled TI sdk prebuilt binaries and using Ti Arago Project filesystem.

I want to install ntp and gpsd packages for my application.

I am using `opkg install ntp` but it is showing error:

```
unknown package ntp.
opkg install cmd: Cannot install package ntp.
```

I also tried opkg update, but there was not any update.

I have tried pinging Google IP address and it was showing the ping address is available.

Please suggest for opkg and ntp issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure /etc/opkg/base-feeds.conf (or /etc/opkg/arago-armv7a-feed.conf) points at the correct server ([Updating Existing Images](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.0/poky-ref-manual/poky-ref-manual.html#usingpoky-changes-updatingimages)). And also make sure ntp package exist on the server. For example, there is no ntp package for [2009.11](http://arago-project.org/files/releases/2009.11/ipk/armv7a/) release.

If you have package (ntp.v123.ipk) downloaded at beaglebone, you can install it with command:

```
opkg install ntp.v123.ipk
```

BTW. It is not so hard to rebuild Arago image from scratch. In that case you can build what ever package you want ([Setting Up Build Environment](http://arago-project.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_Up_Build_Environment)).